# How to create a variable amount of picture boxes in VB using arrays?

Tags: vb.net, cookies

I have the following code that, and as you may see, im trying to make it when the user presses the button it takes the amount of "chocolate chips" they want and puts them on a certain range on the form.  Im not getting any errors, but no chocolate chips are showing.

```
Private Sub cookiesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cookiesButton.Click
        Dim XCoord As Integer
        Dim YCoord As Integer
        Dim arraySize As Integer = Integer.TryParse(cookiesTextBox.Text, arraySize)
        Dim loopCount As Integer = 0
        Dim chipCount(arraySize) As PictureBox
        Do
            loopCount += 1
            If loopCount > arraySize Then Exit Do
            chipCount(loopCount) = New PictureBox
            Controls.Add(chipCount(loopCount))
            Do Until XCoord > 0 And YCoord > 0
                XCoord = (Rnd() * 10)
                YCoord = (Rnd() * 10)
            Loop
            chipCount(loopCount).Image = My.Resources.Chocolae_chip_
            If YCoord < 40 Then YCoord += 40
            If YCoord > 362 Then YCoord -= 40
            If XCoord < 116 Then XCoord += 116
            If XCoord > 408 Then XCoord -= 116
            chipCount(loopCount).Top = YCoord
            chipCount(loopCount).Width = 50
            chipCount(loopCount).Height = 50
            chipCount(loopCount).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            chipCount(loopCount).Left = XCoord
            chipCount(loopCount).Visible = True

            ' --------------------------------------------------------

            XCoord = 0
            YCoord = 0
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
Dim arraySize As Integer = Integer.TryParse(cookiesTextBox.Text, arraySize)
```

`Integer.TryParse` returns either True or False, depending on whether `cookiesTextBox.Text` was successfully parsed as an integer or not. When you assign the return value to `arraySize`, those get converted to -1 or 0. You should instead write something like

```
Dim arraySize As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse(cookiesTextBox.Text, arraySize) Then
    ' TODO: Display an error message.
    Return
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Liu beat me to the TryParse error, but there is a cleaner way to do this.  I would approach this more like this:

```
if Integer.TryParse(cookiesTextBox.Text, chipCount ) then

    For n as integer = 0 to chipCount 
       Dim pic as New PictureBox  

       With pic
          ' ... set all the properties
          .Image = My.Resources.Chocolae_chip_
          .Top = YCoord           ' etc etc etc
          ' ....
       End With
       Me.Contols.Add(pic)
    Next n
 End If
```

There is no real need for an array, since they will exist in the controls collection. A For/Next loop is much better than a Do/Loop since you know how many times you want to loop.